# извлечь информацию о шрифте из PDF

Tags: pdf, gnu, поиск-программ

Посоветуйте опенсорс утилиту, чтобы просмотреть шрифт и параметры документа PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Консольная утилита. Есть компилированные бинарники под Win. Шрифты считывает, свойства тоже. Пример вывода:

```
...\xpdfbin-win-3.04\xpdfbin-win-3.04\bin32>pdfinfo.exe dcp8070d.pdf
Title:
Author:
Creator:        FrameMaker 6.0
Producer:       Acrobat Distiller 5.0.5 (Windows)
CreationDate:   08/24/09 09:57:15
ModDate:        09/05/12 16:18:52
Tagged:         no
Form:           AcroForm
Pages:          652
Encrypted:      yes (print:yes copy:yes change:no addNotes:no)
Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4) (rotated 0 degrees)
File size:      20792844 bytes
Optimized:      yes
PDF version:    1.6
.............
Config Error: No display font for 'ZapfDingbats'
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
LGNIIL+Arial,Italic                  TrueType          yes yes no    6922  0
LGNJCJ+Arial,Bold                    TrueType          yes yes no    6924  0
LGNJDL+Arial                         TrueType          yes yes no    6926  0
LGNIIL+Arial,Italic                  TrueType          yes yes no    3974  0
DOMEFB+Arial,Bold                    TrueType          yes yes no    3972  0
DOMEGD+Arial                         TrueType          yes yes no    3970  0
DOMFDA+Helvetica                     Type 1C           yes yes no    3978  0
DOMEPA+Wingdings-Regular             CID TrueType      yes yes no    3975  0
```

Подойдёт?: http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/

Comment: pdffonts.exe - понравилось, спсб!